# Too many arguments on symlink Symfony

Tags: symfony

Im following the Book of Symfony and when I try to create a symlink between the assets of a bundle and I execute:

```
 php app/console assets:install target [--symlink]
```

I get:

```
 [RuntimeException]   
 Too many arguments.  
 assets:install [--symlink] target
```

Why is this happening? Im copying the command from the book, and my app is too small, I havent done any big changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command it not correct.

The **[--symlink]** it optional this is why its in the brakets. The target means the target where the folder should go to.

So you can try:

```
php app/console assets:install web
php app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

for example. Then you install the assets to web.

Comment: as you can see Im a noob when it comes to console commands, thanks!